# What’s the difference between “tool” and “utility”?

Tags: differences, nouns, terminology, computing

I find these two words appear together often, especially mentioned as *tool* and *utility* for the Unix operating system. So I am wondering about the difference between them.

Comment: Please can you expand your question with examples of where you have seen *tool* and *utility* used in a way that confuses the meanings.

Answer (score 11):

They are used pretty interchangeably when talking about software.  One explanation from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_software):

> Utility software is system software designed to help analyze, configure, optimize or maintain a computer. A single piece of utility software is usually called a *utility or tool*.

"Tool" is *sometimes* reserved for items that are more robust, such as having a GUI or more functionality.  One example of this distinction can be found in the description of the [Visual Studio power tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963.aspx):

> Power Tools are a set of enhancements, tools and command-line utilities.

However, that distinction is mostly a matter of preference.

Comment: These two words are pretty much synonymous, but only in certain contexts, that of computer software. In other contexts this, naturally, won't work - a hammer is a *tool*, but it's certainly not a *utility*. In the US, *utilities* is used to describe the money paid for electricity, water, heating and other such household services, while *tools* is meaningless in that context.

Context is everything.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan:  Yes, I agree.  Since the OP mentioned Unix, I felt that was the desired context and constrained my answer accordingly.  Your explanation seems like it would be a good alternate answer for the broader meaning.

Comment: I think that your answer gave the OP everything he needed, but I just wanted to have a comment with disambiguation in case some future searcher in without the OP's context. :)

Answer (score 7):

Both *tool* and *utility* are nouns, but, while *tool* is a concrete noun, *utility* is an abstract noun, meaning the use one gets out of something. In computing, of course, both are ***[Metaphors](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf)***, since [all computing terms](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/meta4compute.html) are metaphors. But they're different metaphors.

*Tool* refers to the classic book *[Software Tools](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/routledge/regex.html)* by Kernighan and Plauger, and the popular movement it spawned, leading ultimately to [UNIX](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/routledge/unixlanguage.pdf)™ as the premier "tool"-based operating system.

*[Utility](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~j-hamer/210/toolbox_toc.html#SEC1)*, on the other hand, refers to a particular kind of low-level "tool" programs, the "utility programs". This is the same construction as *"utility outfielder"* -- on the other hand, *"utility crew"*  is a different construction that refers to the extension of *Utility/ies* to refer to electric, gas, water, sewage, and other common civic services.

*"Utility programs"* are the ones that do general-purpose  software scutwork, like copying, compressing, sorting, and filtering. Many UNIX™ tool programs are utility programs -- `rev, sort, ls, mv, head`, etc.

Comment: It's a trade mark. In all caps.

Comment: I’m aware of that.  I’m also aware of the wars about it.  Ken and Dennis always used *Unix*, and that’s good enough for me. The lawyers can go hang.  People use *Unix* to mean anything that acts like Unix, including MacOS and Linux.  That’s the common, and most normal, use.  If you want the trademark, put a ™ there.

Comment: I'd intended to, but my Apple "Special Characters" folder needs to be restarted again. So sue me.

Comment: @tchrist: A lot of people referring to "Unix-like" operating systems would use the term **nix*.

Comment: In a community where everyone is familiar with regular expressions, no problemo.  Anywhere else, "Huh?". And how does one pronounce that, by the way? /'starnɪks/? /'splætnɪks/? /'æstərɪsknɪks/?

Comment: While `*nix` could be a regular expression, the asterisk is no evidence of that. An asterisk is only a star operator when it follows another character.

Comment: Depends on the dialect. rm * works fine.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I'd prefer *Asterisknix* over anything else.

Answer (score 4):

I tend to use *tools* for standalone programs designed to do a particular thing, and *utils* for libraries and components for building applications and tools.

Comment: Utilities often include a number of different tools, eg diskutil: http://ss64.com/osx/diskutil.html

Answer (score 2):

**tool:**

> something that helps you to do a particular activity.

because in Unix there are certain tools that executes some specific activity.

**utility**

> to use something in an effective way.

Same way there are some utilities that provides the user to do something very efficiently and effective way.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding apps, *utility* is a type of *tool* handling infrastructure as maintenance (copying, formatting, partitioning, compressing, defragmentation). A *tool* is an app in general with a practical use, like an algorithm calculating some input.